# Django Server Error 500 after changing Debug to False

Tags: python, django, heroku

Am trying to deploy Django app to heroku. Followed this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python)

On running heroku local web (or even python manage.py runserver) and invoking the server, getting a Server Error 500.  Help me out to resolve this error.

Here's my `settings.py` file. [Allowed hosts is set to * for testing]

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Comment: You should set up [error reporting emails](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports) in order to get an email with your exception stack trace.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to assist you.  please provide the exception that would likely be associated with the 500 status code and with that if possible the code pointed at by the stack trace.

Comment: @ihasadad There was no stack trace if debug is false and if debug is true then the error itself is not coming

Comment: @schwobaseggl Since am testing it locally, unable to send error email even though the admins are configured

Comment: @KalyanDechiraju Then you should properly configure logging. If nothing helps, wrap the entire view code in a `try-except` and log the stacktrace... Without knowing the exception and its source you'll be left guessing.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I did a trail and error commenting out the newly added code from heroku and found that this part is causing trouble. If I comment out the last statement `STATICFILES_STORAGE`, then page loads but static css doesn't load.

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

Answer (score 0):

add **static3** in *requirements.txt*

add below lines in *wsgi.py*

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

add below lines in settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```